# http requests and file sizes

Tags: sprite, css-sprites

Hi all I'm in the process of finding out all about sprites and how they can speed up your pages.

So I've used spriteMe to create a overall sprite image which is 130kb, this is made up of 14 images with a combined total size of about 65kb

So is it better to have one http request and a file size of 130kb or 14 requests for a total of 65kb?

Also there is a detailed image which has been put into the spite which caused it's size to go up by about 60kb odd, this used to be a seperate jpg image which was only 30kb. Would I be better off having it seperate and suffering the additional request?

Answer (score 0):

This can depend.  14 requests would be improved by combining items into one request becuase limiting the http requests is where you want to get to as this will make your page more responsive as one request although larger is less blocking then 14 smaller requests.

I say it depends, because sometimes it makes sense to split sprites down into groups of related items as apposed to having one big sprite for everything, this will depend on the complexity of projects, if you are dealing with a simple set of images, one sprite works very well.

Comment: Ok, well if this was you, would you say it's better to have 1 http request for an image of 130kb or 14 for images which individually are about 5kb each and add up to around 65kb?